# Flutter: Bottom part of the screen doesnt show up in release apk of android and adhoc build of ios

Tags: flutter

When i run my app from android studio, my screen renders fine.
[image]

However, when i create and install an apk or create an adhoc build for ios, my screen renders like this:

[image]

As you see the textfield and the buttons below it dont show up. I dont understand what is going wrong. Can you help please.

This is the code for the screen:

```
var child = Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              //flex: 90,
              child: Image.asset(
                "${Constants.imagesPath}login-cover-bg.png",
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              //flex: 100,
              child: Container(
                child: ListView(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50, left: 25),
                      child: Text(
                        'Please sign in',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          fontSize: 22,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 40,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.orange,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, bottom: 15, right: 25),
                        child: TextField(
                          maxLines: 1,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                          onSubmitted: (_) {
                            _checkEmailValid();
                            FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
                          },
                          textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                          controller: _emailController,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: disableRedColor),
                              //  when the TextFormField in unfocused
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: themeRedColor),
                              //  when the TextFormField in focused
                            ),
                            border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                            hintText: 'Email',
                            errorText: isEmailValid == true ? '' : 'Invalid email'
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.yellow,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, right: 25),
                        child: TextField(
                          maxLines: 1,
                          onSubmitted: (_) {
                            _checkPasswordValid();
                            FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                          },
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                          textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                          controller: _passwordController,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: disableRedColor),
                                //  when the TextFormField in unfocused
                              ),
                              focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: themeRedColor),
                                //  when the TextFormField in focused
                              ),
                              border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                              hintText: 'Password',
                              errorText: isPasswordValid == true ? '' : 'Invalid password',
                              suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(
                                  shouldObscureText == false ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off,
                                  color: themeRedColor,
                                ),
                                onPressed: (){
                                  setState(() {
                                    shouldObscureText = !shouldObscureText;
                                  });
                                },
                              )
                          ),
                          obscureText: shouldObscureText,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 65,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            Util.navigateView(context, SignupScreen());
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, right: 25),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(
                                  'Forgot Password?',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                      fontSize: 15,
                                      color: Colors.black54),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'Sign up',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                      fontSize: 15,
                                      color: Colors.black54),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        )),
                  ],
                ),
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Container(
            width: 200,
            child: Text(
              'Welcome Back',
              maxLines: 2,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 35,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {

              print('skip press');

              if(isEmailValid && isPasswordValid && _emailController.text.isNotEmpty && _passwordController.text.isNotEmpty){
                  hitTheLoginAPI();
              }
              else {
                isEmailValid = false;
                isPasswordValid = false;
                Util.showToast('Invalid username or password');
              }
            },
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20, bottom: 35),
              width: 80,
              height: 80,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                color: themeRedColor,
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(
                      Icons.arrow_forward,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Skip',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 17),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

what is going wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Expanded widgets inside a ListView. Expanded is supposed to be used inside a Column or a Row instead.

The incorrect usage throws an exception in debug mode & still prints the UI, since it isn't a breaking issue as such.

In release mode however, Flutter does not show errors or warnings - instead it simply shows a greyed out container, which is what is taking up some space on your app in release mode.

Comment: Removing the expanded widget fixed my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with responsiveness. Maybe, You might have used a really small or really large screen size emulator and it didnt fit according to that. Try using the ListView widget.

Comment: Okay i will try

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'SingleChildScrollView' to let the user scroll down
just wrap with widget

```
SingleChildScrollView(
        child:...
);
```

you can also use 'MediaQuery' and adapt the size by the device size
[MediaQuery](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html)

Comment: Okay i will try it